# Model Null reference exception in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The problem is getting null reference exception when passing data from controller to view

I am Passing a model to the view from the controller like this:

```
 {
    ViewBag.PartId = id;
    var viewmodel= new Orderviewmodelnew();
    var order = new OrderMnagernew().GetSingleOrderField(id);
    viewmodel.ProjectId=order.ProjectId;
    return View(viewmodel);
 }
```

And in the View I have code like this

```
 @model DreamTrade.Web.BL.ViewModels.OrderViewModelnew


 Home>Project @Model.ProjectID==null??//projected is of type guid

 Customer :@(Model.CreatedBy??string.empty)

 Project :@Model.ProjectID
     @Model.ProjectDetail

  CreatedBy:@Model.CreatedBy

  Creation Date:@Model.CreationDate

 CompletedBy :@Model.ModifiedBy
 Completion Date:@Model.LastModified

 @Model.Image

   @Html.Action("OrderIndex", "Ordernew", new { PartId = Guid.Parse("C0497A40-2ADE-4B23-BA9F-1694F087C3D0") })
```

I have Tried like this

```
@if(Model.ProjectId==Null)
 {/....}
```

In the controller i tried like this by not passing model if it is null

```
 var order = new OrderMnagernew().GetSingleOrderField(id);
    if(order!=null)
   {
        viewmodel.ProjectId=order.ProjectId;
        return View(viewmodel);

   }
 return View()
```

The problem with this the projectid in the view is showing exception.

I Want to display empty string if it is null and show the remaining part..

Comment: Try using `Model.ProjectId.Any()` in your if statement

Comment: Please, add exception text

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is the exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
@Model.ProjectID==null??string.empty
```

if `ProjectID` is nullable type, you should write:

```
@(Model.ProjectID ?? string.empty)
```

**Added:**

Replace:

```
return View()
```

with:

```
return View(new Orderviewmodelnew())
```

because `null` object doesn't have any properties

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 2:  
Line 3:  
Line 4:  Home>Project @(Model.ProjectID??Guid.NewGuid())
Line 5:  
Line 6:  Customer :@Model.CreatedBy

Comment: @user2189168 You passing null to view, look at updated answer

Comment: Thnx worked...Do you have any reference material for these type of errors...to learn for me quickly

Answer (score 0):

By putting

```
@model DreamTrade.Web.DALNew.Source
```

at the top of your view, you're making a strongly-typed view which expects a model of that type.

However, in your controller, you're passing a model of type `Orderviewmodel`

You need to make sure the model you pass to the view is of the right type.