# Display model list in ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my controller that return list of my objects:

```
public ActionResult ShowList(string site)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == site).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IQueryable<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowList";
}

    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.fileName</td>
                <td>@item.browser</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Currently get an `NullReferenceException`
I have checked and the return list ins't empty

Comment: Duplicate of [Model Null reference exception in mvc view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699777/model-null-reference-exception-in-mvc-view).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return your `list` in param of `View()` method :

```
public ActionResult ShowList(string site)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == site).ToList();
    return View(list);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type public definition for 'getenumerator' what i am ding wrong ?

Comment: Change in your view the declaration of the model from `IQueryable` to `List<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture>`.

Comment: BTW, how can i order this object with all its properties in listview maybe